# First time running filereader creates nosuchelement exception

Tags: java, java-io

I have created a method called `fileWriter` which outputs an array of random ints into a txt file. This works correctly, but than when I try to use my other method of `fileReader` which is supposed to read that file and add it to another array it will give me a `NoSuchElementException` even though the file has been created(I have checked). The second time I run the program it does work like it is supposed to but the file now has twice as many numbers as it did before. I have tried to create a blank file before importing the array into it but the first time I run the program it still gives me the same error message. If anyone could give a hint on why this is happening it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
/*******************************************************************************/ 
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class randomNum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        FileWriter f;
        try {
//here i create a blank file to try and fix the NoSuchElements exception
            PrintWriter x=new PrintWriter(f=new                 FileWriter("C:\\LOG\\a3Unsorted.txt"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Random gen = new Random();

//This creates the original array 
        int[] array=new int[10];

        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            int rdm=gen.nextInt(100);

            array[i]= rdm;              
        }
    //call the other class  
        Sort num = new Sort(array);

        //call method fileWrite from class Sort to send the array to the file

        Sort.fileWrite(array);

    //call method fileRead from class Sort to read the file thats been created (this is where i think could be the issue)   

        Sort.fileRead(array);

        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }//prints out the array from the file in default output

        }

}
    /***************************************************************************/

import java.io.*;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sort {
    private static PrintWriter out;
    private static FileWriter file;


    public Sort(int[] array) {
    }
    /***************************************************************************/   
    public static void fileRead(int[] array){

        Scanner s = null;
        try {

        s = new Scanner(new File("C:\\LOG\\a3Unsorted.txt"));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        array = new int[s.nextInt()];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            array[i] = s.nextInt();


    }
    /**************************************************************************/
    public static void fileWrite(int[]array){

        try {
            out = new PrintWriter(file = new FileWriter("C:\\LOG\\a3Unsorted.txt",true));
            for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
            {
                out.println(array[i]);
            }
            out.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    }


}//class
```

Comment: Could you please post the stack trace of your exception?

Comment: Here is the stack trace that i get when i run the program:

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at Sort.fileRead(Sort.java:82)
 at randomNum.main(randomNum.java:30)

Answer (score 0):

At this line

```
 array = new int[s.nextInt()];
```

there's something very wrong. What you actually do is to read the first number from the file and then instantiate an array with the length given by this number. I don't think this is what you want to. If this number is larger than the amount of remaining numbers to be read, you will get the exception when you'll try to read beyond the end of the file.

But what's the point in passing the `array` parameter to this method

```
public static void fileRead(int[] array)
```

, if you assign a new array instance to the `array` variable? The original reference will be lost.

Anyway, your code is a little messy with lots of statics and unused variables, e.g. the constructor of `Sort`.